# GCC to emit ARM idiv instructions

Tags: gcc, arm

How can I instruct `gcc` to emit `idiv` (integer division, `udiv` and `sdiv`) instructions for `arm application processors`?

So far only way I can come up with is to use `-mcpu=cortex-a15` with gcc 4.7.

```
$cat idiv.c
int test_idiv(int a, int b) {
    return a / b;
}
```

On gcc 4.7 (bundled with [Android NDK r8e](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html))

```
$gcc -O2 -mcpu=cortex-a15 -c idiv.c
$objdump -S idiv.o

00000000 <test_idiv>:
   0:   e710f110    sdiv    r0, r0, r1
   4:   e12fff1e    bx  lr
```

Even this one gives `idiv.c:1:0: warning: switch -mcpu=cortex-a15 conflicts with -march=armv7-a switch [enabled by default]` if you add `-march=armv7-a` next to `-mcpu=cortex-a15` and doesn't emit `idiv` instruction.

```
$gcc -O2 -mcpu=cortex-a15 -march=armv7-a -c idiv.c

idiv.c:1:0: warning: switch -mcpu=cortex-a15 conflicts with -march=armv7-a switch [enabled by default]

$objdump -S idiv.o
00000000 <test_idiv>:
   0:   e92d4008    push    {r3, lr}
   4:   ebfffffe    bl  0 <__aeabi_idiv>
   8:   e8bd8008    pop {r3, pc}
```

On gcc 4.6 (bundled with Android NDK r8e) it doesn't emit `idiv` instructions at all but recognizes `-mcpu=cortex-a15` also doesn't complain to `-mcpu=cortex-a15 -march=armv7-a` combination.

Afaik `idiv` is optional on `armv7`, so there should be a cleaner way to instruct gcc to emit them but how?

Comment: Are you sure there is an actual instruction called `idiv`? I can only find `sdiv` (signed division) and `udiv` (unsigned division) ...

Comment: @unwind I assume idiv = sdiv | udiv

Comment: Which CPU specifically is your target?  AFAIK the Cortex-A15 supports sdiv/udiv but the Cortex-A5 does not.  Both are ARMv7-A compatible.

Comment: @AustinPhillips Nothing special, I'm just trying to understand if there is a way to tell gcc to spill idiv instructions instead of linking to __aeabi* stuff. One example might be to build Android stack for an emulator which supports idiv.

Comment: The warning **conflicts with** looks like a bug.  Just don't specify an `-march`. See [arm.c](http://gcc.gnu.org/viewcvs/gcc/trunk/gcc/config/arm/arm.c?revision=197425&view=markup), lines 1644-  Or maybe this logic is just to address the situation.  Since you requested a *CPU* that is *better* than the *ARCH*, the *ARCH* is not valid.  I think you just want a *naked* `-mcpu=cortex-a7` (or `-mcpu=cortex-a15`, `-mcpu=cortex-r5`) to get *idiv*; these are the only CPU's that support it and they are better than the *ARCH*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the instruction is not in the *machine descriptions*, then I doubt that `gcc` will emit code. <sup>Note1</sup>

You can always use *inline-assembler* to get the instruction if the compiler is not supporting it.<sup>Note2</sup>  Since your `op-code` is fairly rare/machine specific, there is probably not so much effort to get it in the `gcc` source.  Especially, there are *arch* and *tune/cpu* flags.  The *tune/cpu* is for a more specific machine, but the *arch* is suppose to allow all *machines* in that architecture. This `op-code` seems to break that rule, if I understand.

For `gcc` 4.6.2, it looks like *thumb2* and *cortex-r4* are cues to use these instructions and as you have noted with `gcc` 4.7.2, the *cortex-a15* seems to be added to use these instructions.  With `gcc` 4.7.2, the *thumb2.md* file no longer has `udiv`/`sdiv`.  However, it might be included somewhere else; I am not 100% familiar with all the *machine description* language.  It also seems that *cortex-a7*, *cortex-a15*, and *cortex-r5* may enable these instructions with 4.7.2. <sup>Note3</sup>

This doesn't answer the question directly, but it does give some information/path to get the answer.  You can compile the module with `-mcpu=cortex-r4`, although this may produce linker issues.  Also, there is `int my_idiv(int a, int b) __attribute__ ((__target__ ("arch=cortexe-r4")));`, where you can specify on a per-function basis the *machine-description* used by the code generator.  I haven't used any of these myself, but they are only possibilities to try.  Generally you don't want to keep the wrong machine as it could generate sub-optimal (and possibly illegal) op-codes.  You will have to experiment and maybe then provide the **real** answer.

**Note1:** This is for a *stock* `gcc` 4.6.2 and 4.7.2.  I don't know if your Android compiler has patches.

```
gcc-4.6.2/gcc/config/arm$ grep [ius]div *.md
arm.md: "...,sdiv,udiv,other"
cortex-r4.md:;; We guess that division of A/B using sdiv or udiv, on average, 
cortex-r4.md:;; This gives a latency of nine for udiv and ten for sdiv.
cortex-r4.md:(define_insn_reservation "cortex_r4_udiv" 9
cortex-r4.md:       (eq_attr "insn" "udiv"))
cortex-r4.md:(define_insn_reservation "cortex_r4_sdiv" 10
cortex-r4.md:       (eq_attr "insn" "sdiv"))
thumb2.md:  "sdiv%?\t%0, %1, %2"
thumb2.md:   (set_attr "insn" "sdiv")]
thumb2.md:(define_insn "udivsi3"
thumb2.md:      (udiv:SI (match_operand:SI 1 "s_register_operand"  "r")
thumb2.md:  "udiv%?\t%0, %1, %2"
thumb2.md:   (set_attr "insn" "udiv")]
```

```
gcc-4.7.2/gcc/config/arm$ grep -i [ius]div *.md
arm.md:  "...,sdiv,udiv,other"
arm.md:  "TARGET_IDIV"
arm.md:  "sdiv%?\t%0, %1, %2"
arm.md:   (set_attr "insn" "sdiv")]
arm.md:(define_insn "udivsi3"
arm.md: (udiv:SI (match_operand:SI 1 "s_register_operand"  "r")
arm.md:  "TARGET_IDIV"
arm.md:  "udiv%?\t%0, %1, %2"
arm.md:   (set_attr "insn" "udiv")]
cortex-a15.md:(define_insn_reservation "cortex_a15_udiv" 9
cortex-a15.md:       (eq_attr "insn" "udiv"))
cortex-a15.md:(define_insn_reservation "cortex_a15_sdiv" 10
cortex-a15.md:       (eq_attr "insn" "sdiv"))
cortex-r4.md:;; We guess that division of A/B using sdiv or udiv, on average, 
cortex-r4.md:;; This gives a latency of nine for udiv and ten for sdiv.
cortex-r4.md:(define_insn_reservation "cortex_r4_udiv" 9
cortex-r4.md:       (eq_attr "insn" "udiv"))
cortex-r4.md:(define_insn_reservation "cortex_r4_sdiv" 10
cortex-r4.md:       (eq_attr "insn" "sdiv"))
```

**Note2:** See [pre-processor as Assembler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15465958/using-gccs-pre-processor-as-an-assembler) if `gcc` is passing options to `gas` that prevent use of the `udiv/sdiv` instructions.  For example, you can use `asm(" .long <opcode>\n");` where *opcode* is some token pasted stringified register encode macro output.  Also, you can annotate your assembler to specify changes in the `machine`.  So you can temporarily *lie* and say you have a *cortex-r4*, etc.

**Note3:**

```
gcc-4.7.2/gcc/config/arm$ grep -E 'TARGET_IDIV|arm_arch_arm_hwdiv|FL_ARM_DIV' *
arm.c:#define FL_ARM_DIV    (1 << 23)         /* Hardware divide (ARM mode).  */
arm.c:int arm_arch_arm_hwdiv;
arm.c:  arm_arch_arm_hwdiv = (insn_flags & FL_ARM_DIV) != 0;
arm-cores.def:ARM_CORE("cortex-a7",  cortexa7,  7A, ... FL_ARM_DIV
arm-cores.def:ARM_CORE("cortex-a15", cortexa15, 7A, ... FL_ARM_DIV
arm-cores.def:ARM_CORE("cortex-r5",  cortexr5,  7R, ... FL_ARM_DIV
arm.h:  if (TARGET_IDIV)                                \
arm.h:#define TARGET_IDIV               ((TARGET_ARM && arm_arch_arm_hwdiv) \
arm.h:extern int arm_arch_arm_hwdiv;
arm.md:  "TARGET_IDIV"
arm.md:  "TARGET_IDIV"
```

Comment: (+1) Thanks for giving some courage for machine definitions, I think I can define a new machine type like *armv7-ad* copying from armv7-a. I don't think you can use inline assembler, compiler will still cry over mismatching instruction. About mach, mcpu, mtune... So integer div is optional, it is optional to mach... then I would expect either a mach variation or some extra flag like fpu. I expect mcpu/mtune to give optimizer some instruction scheduling information - that's why I hesitate to use cortex-a15.

Comment: @auselen Did you try `-mcpu=cortex-a7`?  Or that is not for your machine?  It looks like it gives the same *FL_ARM_DIV* permissions as the `-mcpu=cortex-a15`.

Comment: Nope. Let's assume I use a cortex-a9 with idiv support. May be I can use "-mcpu=cortex-a15 -mtune=cortex-a9", I'll test that later.

Comment: Ok, the cortex-a9 doesn't support it in gcc-4.7.  You can change the [*arm-cores.def*](http://gcc.gnu.org/viewcvs/gcc/trunk/gcc/config/arm/arm-cores.def?revision=197346&view=markup) to make a new *core* like *cortex-a9-div* and then use the `FL_ARM_DIV` flag to say that is supports *idiv* (copying the existing *cortex-a9*).  Then you could use `-mcpu=cortex-a9-div`.  Probably no `gcc` support this yet.  It looks like `-mcpu=cortex-a7` is an alternative pick. Cortex a7,a9,a15 all have different schedulers.

Comment: @auselen Hmm, but only the `cortex-a15` has the schedule stuff for *idiv*.  Even the `cortex-a7` is missing it.  Maybe better to post to a `gcc` mailing list, to get some part of the scheduler working.

Comment: So it is somehow same question, imagine you need to build an app that can work on cortex-a15 or cortex-a7. There should be a generic way to say I want idiv instructions on an armv7. I'm just saying this to state intent of my question.

Comment: @auselen  There are three things the compiler has for the code gen.  Is the `op-code` *allowed*, the cost (number of cycles), and the scheduling.  For non-pipelined arch/CPU, there is no scheduler.  The scheduler just models load/store, multiple execute, MAC unit, etc. and tries to sequence instruction so each stage is *humming*.  Selecting *cortex-a15* and *cortex-a7* will both give permission to use `idiv`.  I expect the costing (cycle/idiv) is the same.  I think your idea of `-mtune=cortex-a9` gives you the right scheduler with permission to use `idiv`; but `idiv` has no scheduling model.

Comment: @auselen  ..has no scheduling model.  So the compiler may mis-place `idiv` if you have *multiplies* in the same code for instance.  However, it is still more efficient than calling `__aeabi_idiv` which is 100-1000s of instructions.

Comment: @auselen To answer your last question, the `cortex-a7` and `cortex-a15` are [identical in arm-cores.def](http://gcc.gnu.org/viewcvs/gcc/trunk/gcc/config/arm/arm-cores.def?revision=197346&view=markup) except the scheduler.  Scroll to the bottom; the code should be compatible, just depending on the one you pick, the code will run faster on one or the other.  If you then go and use `-mtune=cortext-a9`, I don't think it matters which one you pick.

Comment: mtune doesn't effect idiv emitting. idiv is controlled by mcpu so far.

Comment: @auselen Yes, that is what I expect.  `mtune` affect instruction scheduling.  The only issue is the scheduler doesn't know anything about `idiv`.  Otherwise, I believe you are optimal.