# Does the .so file still contain infomation about label

Tags: linux, compilation, arm, reverse-engineering

In what phase of compilation does the compiler replace `label` into actual `addr`

I understanding instructions like `jmp abc` where `abc` is just a note and will be replace to  actual address eventually, does it ?

Does the final `.so` file still contain infomation about `label` or the `label` is replace to actual `addr` when its load in the memory ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL;DR** - your question is hard to answer, because it is mixing a few concepts.  For typical assembler labels, we use PC relative and labels are resolve at assemble time.  For other 'external' labels, there are many cases and the resolution depends on the case.

---

There are four conceptual ways to address on almost all CPUs, and definitely on the ARM.

1. PC relative address.  Current instruction +/- offset.
2. Absolute address.  This is the one you are conceptually thinking of.
3. Register computed address.  Calculated at run time. `ldr pc, [rn, #xx]`
4. Table based addressing.  Global offset table, etc.  Much like registers computed addresses. `ldr pc, [Rbase, Rindex, lsl #2]`

The first two fit in a single instruction and are very efficient.  The first is most desirable as the code can execute at *ANY* address as long as it maintains it's original layout (ie, you don't load it by splitting the code up).

In the table above, there is also the concept of 'build time' and 'run time'.  The distinction is the difference between a **linker** and a **loader**. You have tagged this 'linux' and refer to an 'so' or shared library.  Also, you are referring to assembler 'labels'.  They are very similar concepts, but can be different as they will be one of the four classes of addressing above.

Most often in assembler, the labels are PC relative.  There is no additional structure to be implemented with PC relative, except to keep the chunk of code continuous.  In the case of an assembler that is a 'module' (compilation unit, for a compile) or is processed by the assembler and produced an 'object', it will use a PC relative addressing.

The object format can be annotate with external addresses and there are many  choices in how an assembler may output these address.  They are generally  controlled by 'psuedo-ops'.  That is a note (separate section with defined format) in the object file; the instruction is semi-complete in this form.  It may prepare to use an offset table, use a register based compute (like `r9`+constant), etc.

For the typical case of linking (done at build time), we will either use PC relative or absolute.  If we fix our binary to only run at one address, the assembler can setup for absolute addressing and resolve these through linking.  In this case, the binary must be loaded at a fixed address.  The assembler 'modules' or object files can be completely glued together to have everything resolved.  Then there is no 'load' time fix ups.  Other determining factor are whether code/data are separate, and whether the system is using an MMU.  It is often desirable to keep code constant, so that many processes can use the same RAM/ROM pages, but they will have separate data.  As well as memory efficient, this can provide some form of security (although it is not extremely robust) it will prevent accidental code overwrites and will provide debugging help in the form of SIGSEGV.

It is possible to write a PC-relative initialization routine which will do the fix-ups to create a table in your own binary.  So a 'loader' is just to determine where you are running and then make calculations.  For **statically** shared libraries, you typically know the libraries you will run, but not where they are.  For **dynamically** shared libraries, you might not even know at compile time what the library is that you will run.

A Linux distribution can use either.  If you have some sort of standard Linux Desktop distribution, (Ubuntu/Debian, Redhat, etc). You will have something base on ARM ELF LSB and dynamic shared libraries.  You need to use the assembler pseudo ops to support this type of addressing or use a compiler to do it for you.  The majority of all 'labels' in a shared library will be PC relative and not show up.  Some labels can show up for debugging reasons (`man strip`) and some are absolutely needed to resolve addresses at run time.

I have also asked a question that I find related some time ago, [Using GCC pre-processor as an assembler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15465958/using-gccs-pre-processor-as-an-assembler)... So the key concept is that the assembler is generally 'two pass' and needs to do these local address fix ups.  Then this question asks a 2nd level Concept A/B where we are adding shared libraries.  The online book [Linkers and Loaders](http://www.davidsalomon.name/assem.advertis/asl.pdf) is a great resource if you want to known more.

See also:

- [Static linked shared libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25172834/how-to-create-static-linked-shared-libraries)
- [Thumb start function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20369440/can-start-be-the-thumb-function)
- [What is the point of busybox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57353552/whats-the-point-of-using-busybox-in-a-low-ram-embedded-system)

Answer (score 2):

Final executable has to have all addresses, otherwise it would not work.

Thing to remember is there are static linking and dynamic linking (eg using shared libraries). In case of static linkage binary file has all addresses resolved. In case of dynamic linkage addresses are resolved during loading, while binary has relocation information that are replaced with actual addresses by dynamic linker. But by the end of a day, loaded binary in memory has all addresses.

> In what phase of compilation does the compiler replace label into
> actual addr

Compiler could replace with actual address when it knows destination address. For example that's a call to function in same compilation unit.

When destination address is outside of compilation unit and out of reach for compiler, compiler leaves a relocation information in object file. Linker replace that with an actual address in memory at same time.

Comment: This is a great answer, but it is untrue that 'the executable has to have all addresses'.  In fact the techniques for not having an address allow a lot of mal-ware and shared libraries to function.  If you do not have  a 'loader', then this is correct.  A loader can exist as part of your own code, or you can use 'ldd' or some other system loader to determine final addresses at run time.  For most embedded programmer (bare metal), we would not use a loader.  A loader is simply code that will preform the runtime fix up in various ways.